# Join In Pandas on Between

Tags: python, pandas, join

I'm hoping to recreate a join I would normally run in SQL (but can't because our version of presto won't run jsonb columns which I need to use to filter one of the tables) in python using pandas dataframes:

```
SELECT 
t1.a,
t1.b   
FROM t1
JOIN df2 ON t1.a = t2.a
AND t1.b BETWEEN t2.c AND t2.d
```

Is there a way I can set this up with dataframes in python instead of tables in SQL?

Comment: Kindly create sample dataframe with expected output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pandas doesn't have a direct way to do this. You need to merge and filter later:

```
df1.merge(df2, on='a').query('c<=b<=d')
```